# Automating a histogram for varying excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I was writing some code with which I need some help with. The code I have written (posted below) has to do a couple of things, first and foremost it should be able to create a histogram (which it does) from a file which it reads and bin it accordingly. So here is where I need some help, 1) I need to find a way to change the bin width to any arbitrary width I would need (deltaT), without having to hard code it every time, 2) the I need some help being able to run the code for different excel files imported into python and have them exported as different excel files. I believe, I'm not so sure I'm pretty new to coding, that what I'm dealing with is a Dataframe. Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
from pandas import ExcelWriter

data = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/Book1.xlsx')
counts, bins, patches = plt.hist(data.values, bins=range(0, 
int(max(data.values)+5), 5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'bin_leftedge': bins[:-1], 'count': counts})
plt.title('Data')
plt.xlabel('Neuron')
plt.ylabel('# of Spikes')
plt.show()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

I tried having another excel file read as in:

```
data2 = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/Book2.xlsx')
```

and then putting it into the code and having it run, but it only gives out the results for the first excel file (outputs it into another excel file). What am I doing wrong? Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

So I was able to get it to read the multiple files and run the code on them, now the only thing I still can't figure out is how to get them to export as the different excel files they are (plus the bin width change) with the code applied to them. I changed the code a bit to:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os

for file in os.listdir('/Users/user/Desktop/Data'):
    data = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/{0}'.format(file))
    counts, bins, patches = plt.hist(data.values, bins=range(0, 
    int(max(data.values)+5), 5))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'bin_leftedge': bins[:-1], 'count': counts})
    plt.title('Data')
    plt.xlabel('Neuron')
    plt.ylabel('# of Spikes')
    plt.show()

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/ouput.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
```

Again any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So my interpretation of your question is that you're looking to save the histograms as images inside the excel files. Is this correct?

Comment: Not really, what I need to do is have the excel files binned into bins of 5 (which is one thing I need help changing) and then have them exported with the applied bins to an excel file (which it does, but for only one file). It'll pretty much look like a list which counts how many times there is a number between, for example [0,5) there is 2 numbers well the count goes up by 2 and so on and so forth for the rest of the data. It reads the multiple excel files in a directory applies the code BUT only outputs 1 excel file and not all the ones that were imported. The plot is just for show. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only one file is exported because the named *output.xlsx* Excel file in the loop never changes, so it overwrites with each iteration. Consider below that adds a *_bins* suffix to the original Excel file.

```
datadir = '/Users/user/Desktop/Data/'

for file in os.listdir(datadir):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
       data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(datadir, file))

       #...data processing and graph output...

       outfile = os.path.join(datadir, file.replace('.xlsx', '_bins.xlsx'))
       writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfile)
       df.to_excel(writer)
       writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother it worked! You saved my life